# Cannot set LED monitor to native resolution

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, dvi

I cannot get windows 7 pro to set my monitor to its native resolution of 2650x1440.

I have Windows 7 pro, an NVIDIA GT730 and two monitors(AOC e2752She, BenQ GW2765) attached to the NVidia card using the DVI ports using this cable: ([http://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-HDMI-DVI-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00NH11X64?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_search_detailpage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NH11X64)). I originally only had the AOC with a native resolution of 1920x1080. Then I got the BenQ, but on setting it up Windows would only allow 1920x1080 for it. So I went into the Nvidia control panel and created a custom resolution 2560x1440 and set it to that. Superficially it looks like it did it as the background got small for it and the conrol panel/display/screen resolution setting SAYS 2650x1440, but the image is "soft", not crisp and when I look at the information panel on the display itself, the monitor says it is being driven at 1920x1080 and its recommended setting is 2650x1440, so I'm thinking that windows must be doing some emulation of 2560x1440 and not actually pushing it natively at 2560x1440. Even if I set the monitor to 1920x1080 the image is really "soft".

I want to use this monitor (gw2765) for graphic design and video editing, so I really need it to show it's true resolution. I have searched for quite a long time and have not found anything that seems to address this issue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!